# How to populate countryList data in Form.Select in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express

I have a data file that contains a list of all countries and I want these countries to populate in a select input similar to what we see on popular websites when a user logs in and visits his profile page to edit his information such as name, address and country.

but when I run my code it doesn't seem to populate anything.

what am I doing wrong?

here is my code:

data.js

```
export const countryList = [
    "Afghanistan",
    "Albania",
    "Algeria",
    "American Samoa",
    "Andorra",
    "Angola",
    "Anguilla",
    "Antarctica",....,....,.....]
```

profile.js:

```
    import { countryList, documentList,shipmentPurposeList } from "../LocalData/data"
    import React, {Component, useState, useEffect} from 'react';
      const [country,setCountry] = useState([]);
    
      useEffect(() => {
            Axios.get('http://localhost:3001/login').then((response) => {
    
                if(response.data.loggedIn == true){
            
                 setCountry(countryList);
                }
            });
        },[]);


     return (

      <Row>
                      <Col md={11}>
                          <Form.Group controlId="exampleForm.ControlInput1"> 
                          <Form.Label className={'font-12 mt-3 color-gray inputLabel'}>Country</Form.Label>
                            <Form.Select aria-label="Select Title">

                                  { country.map((item, i) => {
                                                 
                                     <option key={i} value={item}>
                                      {item}
                                      </option>
                                     
                                     })
                                   }
                                  </Form.Select>
                                 </Form.Group>
                             </Col>
                          </Row>
)
```

Comment: Is `setCountry(countryList);` inside axios actually running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a syntax "error", your `map` callback function doesn't return the JSX element, it just defines it

It should be

```
{ country.map((item, i) => (
                                                 
                                     <option key={i} value={item}>
                                      {item}
                                      </option>
                                     
                                     ))
                                   }
```

Notice the round brackets after the arrow, instead of curly braces. Round brackets meaning you want to return whatever's in there, whilst curly braces define the body of the function.

Comment: thats amazing. thank you. you were right. it was just a syntax error thank you so much